# How do you let 2 objects owned by a parent object talk to one another in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop

First off, I'm sorry if this is a n00b question. I'm a self-taught web developer and this is my first real foray into apps. I've tried to find the answer to what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure on the proper terminology and so haven't found any relevant results. I figure this is because either I don't know the right way of asking for what I need; the answer is so obvious it doesn't need writing about or what I'm asking is so stupid the concept doesn't exist and I should be totally doing it another way.

Anyway, on to my question. I'm working on an app that has 3 classes that are giving me trouble. There is the 'MainContainer', which mostly handles the UI; the 'Assigner' which picks out tasks to do; and the 'Worker' which does the tasks. It's in a very early stage, but this is kind of how it looks right now.

```
class MainContainer

  def setup
    @worker = Worker.new(:x => 200, :y => 200)
    @assigner = Assigner.new(:x => 400, :y => 300)
  end

  # update & draw code
end

class Assigner

  def set_target
    parent.worker.target self.x, self.y
  end

  # input, update & draw code
end

class Worker < GameObject

  def target(tx, ty)
    @target_x = tx
    @target_y = ty
    @has_task = true
  end

  # update & draw code
end
```

The basic flow of the app goes something like this: an instance of the MainContainer loads and shows the UI on the screen including the assigner and worker. The user then uses the assigner to move around the UI and choose a task. Everything works fine up until this point.

What I can't figure out is how the Assigner can pass a value to the worker. The code I have in the example is the set_target method of the worker. The `parent.worker.target self.x, self.y` line is the most recent of my attempts. Other things I've tried here include things like `@worker.target self.x, self.y`

I was thinking of passing the `@worker` into the `@assigner`, but the plan is for there to be an arbritrary number of workers that will increase/decrease over time. I plan to handle these with a `WorkerManager` that will keep track of how many workers are currently available, but if I pass this into the @assigner will it not be just a copy of it that is passed? I'm still way off from implementing anything like that so I haven't tested it, perhaps that is the way to go?

Another thing I've thought about is having the worker as a global, but this is a problem that will likely rise again quite frequently so I'd end up with an app full of globals, I'm guessing that's not the right way!

I'm from web-dev so the only other solution I can think of is to database the whole lot of it. This is a last resort if I can't get anything else going though.

Anyway, to re-state my question. In an instance of MainContainer, how do I get its Assigner and Worker to pass data between each other?

I'd really appreciate any help here, even if it goes something like "stfu n00b, read this: -relevant link".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a flaw in the design somewhere. You say that the Assigner picks the task and the Worker does it. It doesn't look like they need to communicate. If they need to, they may be doing more than what you described, which may indicate an opportunity for refactoring into more isolated classes with fewer responsibilities.

So, what if the MainContainer had all control?

```
def main
  @worker = Worker.new
  @assigner = Assigner.new
  target = @assigner.target
  result = @worker.do_work(target)
  update_ui(result)
end
```

The UI should really be separate from the business logic, the pseudocode above just illustrates the idea of giving control to the MainContainer to avoid having the Worker and the Assigner to talk to each other. This will also allow you to handle multiple workers if necessary.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This really helped me on my way and I have it working now. Instead of Assigner passing data to Worker, I have MainContainer taking data from Assigner and passing it to Worker. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be affected by the fact that I am not clearly getting the point of the question, so please have that in mind and do correct me where I am wrong.

The best way would probably be to isolate worker and assigner altogether and put all the logic into the controller.

However, if you need more communication between workers and you want to keep assigners involved into it, then it might be a good idea for the assigner to be aware of the workers it created and the workers to know which assigner created them. Then, the assigners should be responsible for creating the workers (and the controller for creating assigners). Something like (ugly, non-optimised and not tested code):

```
class Assigner
  attr_reader :workers
  def initialize
    @workers = []
  end
  def create_worker
    worker = Worker.new
    worker.assigner = self
    @workers << worker
    worker
  end
end

class Worker
  attr_accessor :assigner
end
```

Of course, you then need to manage the collection of workers per each assigner and e.g. remove the non-active workers once they finish their work.

Everything in Ruby is passed as reference, so no copying of objects in method calls. A [discussion on the ruby forum can be found](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/41160). (This you also wondered about in your question.)

I hope my answer is of some help. If not, please point that out in a comment and I will try to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Having the workers owned by the Assigner isn't really what I'm going for as the workers will also be manipulated by many other parts of the app. However, you've made some very good points that will come in useful, and knowing that everything is passed by reference is a massive help to me. I have the answer I need but thank you very much for your contribution!